# Grails session is closed because of too many open transactions

Tags: grails, transactions, cucumber, fixture

I'm using cucumber to test my grails application. My testing environment uses the h2 database. To create my test data I use fixtures, which I load in the before section

`fixtureLoader.load("fixtures")`

In the after section I drop my database with

```
def configuration = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("&sessionFactory").configuration
def connection = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('dataSource').connection
new SchemaExport( configuration, connection ).create( false, true )
```

The tests run just fine until my session is closed because there are 65535 open transactions.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Allgemeiner Fehler: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are 65535 open transactions [1.4.186/102]"
General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are 65535 open transactions [1.4.186/102]" [50000-186]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.toSQLException(DbException.java:268)
    at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:352)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.commit(JdbcConnection.java:473)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(JdbcConnection.java:430)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:814)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:714)
```

Is there any way to clean up all open transactions after each test run?